# Jquery issue: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am currently building a website with the Meteor framework.  Right now, I am trying to get it so that when I click on an element in the DOM (rendered through handlebars), new elements are appended to the one that was currently clicked. I am doing this with jquery and have included all the proper packages. Unfortunately, when I test what I have, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`.  I've looked around online and I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Here is all the relevant code with comments to explain why I'm doing what I am:

Category template (this is the element I'm trying to append to):

```
<template name="category">
<div class="category">
    <h2 class="text-center category-title"> {{title}} </h2>
    <div class="topics"> </div> <!-- where I want to append -->
</div>
</template>
```

Event handling code:

```
Template.category.events({
   'click .category': function(e){
        var elem = $(this > '.topics'); //grab div to append to
        var category = this;

        console.log(elem); //will log what appears to be a jquery object (output below)

        for (var i = 0; i < category.topics.length; i++){ //loop to append all new elements
            var html = '<div>' + category.topics[i] + '</div>'; 
            elem.append(html); //this is where the error occurs
        }
    }
})
```

Log output:

```
[true, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]
```

Anybody have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This line:

```
var elem = $(this > '.topics')
```

What do you mean by this? First of all, `this` here is a template data context, not a DOM element and certainly not a selector string. On top of that, you use `>` comparison, which returns `false`, so you're effectively left with `$(false)` – probably not what you want.

To get template DOM elements you should use template methods instead of global ones. In your case, that's most probably:

```
var elem = t.$('.topics');
```

Edit: and of course, you should define your function as `function(e, t)` to get the template instance here.

2) You really shouldn't manipulate DOM in that way. You miss out on reactivity, template optimizations, and everything Meteor is doing already for you. A "Meteor way" would be to have the HTML you need already in template, and toggle whether it's shown or hidden by a reactive variable.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input! This fixed my problem and gave me some good insight on how to use meteor more effectively!